# Amazon Mechanical Turk JSON Requester Schema

Tags: json, api, salesforce

Trying to see if we can use Salesforce External Services with Amazon Mechanical Turk API. Salesforce asks for import of JSON schema. So far I'm only finding this reference. Is there a JSON format anyone is aware of or is there a way to convert some of these to JSON? The online sites of seen for conversion do not do whole schema (i.e. headers, results, etc.) so not being accepted.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/Welcome.html